# How to type in movable fields

Tags: testing, types, automation, cypress

I have a little problem in writing my test.

Most of fields on my website I can fill only with "type" element. But there are fields that don't want to fill. But it looks like (in Cypress) that it's OK. They are movable with arrows as shown in the image below.

[image]

When I'm in playground and I want to get that field it looks like this:

[image: The input has a tooltip that contains code.]

Cypress gets that field but don't want to type in it (than should element tells me that it's OK).

Code:

```
.cy.get('[data-bind="validationElement: yearOfManufacture"] > .col-sm-4 > .k-widget > .k-numeric-wrap > .k-formatted-value')

.type('2016')

.should('have.value', '2016')
```

Is there someone who knows what to do?

---

This is how it (DOM in dev-tools) looks like:

```html
<input type="text" class="k-formatted-value w-100 k-input" 
 title="" tabindex="0" role="spinbutton" aria-valuemin="1900" 
 aria-valuemax="2018" autocomplete="off" aria-disabled="false"
 style="display: inline-block;">
```

Comment: If you want to click the arrows in the test, perhaps use the Selector Playground to hover over the arrows to find their selctor, then use `cy.get('arrow-selector-here').click()`. But some more complex controls are difficult to select in Cypress, so it may not be possible.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but this is not what I'm looking for. I know that I can click on that arrow but I need to fill that field with number over 40000 so that need a lot of clicks.
I need to write text it in.

Comment: Ah, I got the question back-to-front. That selector looks very complicated. Another way to find a different selector is to right-click, inspect element and see what the DOM looks like in dev tools. I typically use a class name, but it depends on the particular page. If you could post a section of DOM we can help further.

Comment: From the class names, it looks like Kendo UI is used to make the page.

Comment: This is how it looks like:
<div class="k-animation-container" style="width: 31px; height: 24px; overflow: hidden; top: 891px; z-index: 10002; left: 565px; box-sizing: content-box; display: none; position: absolute;" aria-hidden="true"><div role="tooltip" class="k-widget k-tooltip k-popup k-group k-reset" data-role="popup" style="display: none; position: absolute; opacity: 0;" aria-hidden="true"><div class="k-tooltip-content"><div class="z-popover-technical-card"><div class="popover-content"><img alt="Technický průkaz" src="/images/technicak-zadni.jpg"><div class="area area-vin">

Comment: That class name (k-animation-container) is used in more fields.

Comment: The best suggestion I have is use the force `.type('2016', { force: true })`. Perhaps the text input is being covered by the popover.

Comment: I was trying that but it doesn't work. I am really without any idea.

Comment: Selector Playground suggests class `.k-formatted-value`, but that is not in your DOM post. The question is, where is it in the DOM? It must be there since Cypress Selector Playground found it.

Comment: I get that field so that is not the problem. Problem is that Cypress don't what to type in it.

Comment: I'm sorry I gave you wrong element before. This is the right element: <input type="text" class="k-formatted-value w-100 k-input" title="" tabindex="0" role="spinbutton" aria-valuemin="1900" aria-valuemax="2018" autocomplete="off" aria-disabled="false" style="display: inline-block;">

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class names in the Playground selector indicate that this page is based on Kendo UI, so I ran a test against their demo page for numeric textbox 'https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/numerictextbox/index',

It seems to me that Kendo use two inputs in DOM, one for displaying the formatted value and another for receiving the user's typed input. The second input will appear or come forward when the first gets focus.

This is the test that works for the demo page, I hope it will work for your page as well

```js
describe('KendoUI', () => {

  it('types text into numeric inputs', () => {

    cy.visit('https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/numerictextbox/index');

    const initialValue = '$30.00'
    const displayInput = cy.get(':nth-child(1) > label > .k-widget > .k-numeric-wrap > .k-formatted-value')
      .should('have.value', initialValue)
      .focus()

    const editInput = displayInput.parent()  
      .children('.k-input')
      .eq(1)                // get the 2nd input of this parent, not the first

    const newValue = '2016'
    editInput
      .clear()
      .type(newValue)
      .should('have.value', newValue)

  })
})
```